Using Developer PowerShell for VS 2022 when debugging scripts in Visual Studio Code
I would like to run / debug PowerShell scripts in Visual Studio Code through "Developer PowerShell for VS 2022 x64".
(There is no x64 version of "Developer PowerShell for VS 2022" available by default, I created this with the following thread.)
I have created the below required configuration in the settings.json file in Visual Studio Code:
{
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Developer PowerShell for VS 2022 x64",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "Developer PowerShell for VS 2022 x64": {
            "path": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
            "args": [
                "-noe",
                "-c",
                "&{Import-Module \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Professional\\Common7\\Tools\\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll\"; Enter-VsDevShell b6f9d985}"
            ]
        },
    },
    "powershell.powerShellDefaultVersion": "Developer PowerShell for VS 2022 x64"
}

After applying the configuration, the "Developer PowerShell for VS 2022 x64" shell appeared and loaded correctly via the profile selector:

The goal would be that when I run the PowerShell script, this shell will run it and I would also like to debug it.
Currently, after I select the "Developer PowerShell for VS 2022 x64" shell and press F5 to start debugging, it switches back to the built-in "PowerShell Extension" (it uses "Windows PowerShell" in the background) and runs through that.
It is important to run and debug through this custom shell, because the interpretation of certain language elements differs between "PowerShell Extension" and "Developer PowerShell for VS 2022 x64".

How can I make it execute and debug using the "Developer PowerShell for VS 2022 x64" profile I added?
Current version of my Visual Studio Code:
 Version: 1.92.1 (user setup)
 Commit: eaa41d57266683296de7d118f574d0c2652e1fc4
 Date: 2024-08-07T20:16:39.455Z
 Electron: 30.1.2
 ElectronBuildId: 9870757
 Chromium: 124.0.6367.243
 Node.js: 20.14.0
 V8: 12.4.254.20-electron.0
 OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045*

Thanks for the helpful answers.
